# nginx www.domain.com vs domain.com virtualhost

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, cname-record, a-record

I have an http block where I include virtual hosts for the different domains hosted on the same server. For each virtual host I do:

```
listen domain.com:80;
```

Now, domain2.com works fine. However, when I do www.domain2.com it shows the page for domain1.com!

How to properly configure nginx? Does this have something to do whether `www` is a CNAME or an A record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can do the following in a server block:

```
listen 80;
server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
server {
 listen WHATEVER_IP:80;
 server_name domain2.com;
 ... rest of config for domain2.com goes here
}

server {
 listen WHATEVER_IP:80;
 server_name www.domain2.com;
 ... rest of config for www.domain2.com goes here
}
```

This will work whether the two IPs are the same or not. You can just use `listen 80;` if you don't need different servers on different IPs and everything is name-based.

Comment: Two server blocks for the same configuration?

Comment: You can also merge them and use one server block for each different configuration.